# WildFly: is it possible to communicate between non-ejb services of 2 ears?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, ear

Given I have deployed 2 ears on my WildFly instance. I want to setup some communication between them. The way which seems the most comfortable for me is to use some common bean.

By 'bean' I dont mean ejb-bean because I dont use ejb. Thats an important point. Best option for me is a Spring bean.

Anyway, Spring bean, or just some instance of a some Java class, I would like to have a *shared* instance of some Java object in a memory of *both* ears, deployed on my WildFly.

Is it possible?
If not, what are the options?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a queue in the standalone(-full).xml, two topics for bidirectional communication and have the ears submit and process each other messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not something I would recommend as it tightly couples applications. My general recommendation would be to use some sort of remoting between the applications.

Having that said there are a couple of ways to achieve this. First you have to make sure that both EARs use the same shared classes. The easiest way to do that is to move them to a JBoss module and declare a dependency in your EARs. It is important that the classes are not in the EARs. Then you somehow have to register the objects, JNDI and JMX are obvious candidates.

EJB calls should also be possible but the same rules for shared classes apply (add an interface to the EJB, share the interface between the EARs, refer to the EJB only by interface). There are various ways to make EJBs available to Spring, the obvious one being a factory bean.